# BeautifulSoup nested / embedded identical tags with different classes

Tags: nested, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to parse some html files that frequently have snippets like this:

```
<p class="p5"><p class="s2">In the directory </p>/home/blah/<p class="s2"> there is a file, </p>plotData.dat</p>
```

It gets parsed as this:

```
>>> [c for c in P.body.children]
[<p class="p5"></p>,
 <p class="s2">In the directory </p>,
 u'/home/blah/',
 <p class="s2"> there is a file, </p>,
u'plotData.dat']
```

I expected it to come out as

```
>>> [c for c in P.body.children]
[<p class="p5"></p>,
 <p class="s2">In the directory </p>,
 <p class="p5">u'/home/blah/'</p>,
 <p class="s2"> there is a file, </p>,
 <p class="p5">u'plotData.dat'</a>]
```

So is the input html just malformed?  Is there anything I can do to make the input html parse as the latter?  (I have no control over the appearance of the html)

EDIT: Complete MWE:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
>>> P = BS('<p class="p5"><p class="s2">In the directory </p>/home/blah/<p class="s2"> there is a file, </p>plotData.dat</p>')
>>> [c for c in P.body.children]
[<p class="p5"></p>, <p class="s2">In the directory </p>, u'/home/blah/', <p class="s2"> there is a file, </p>, u'plotData.dat']
```

Comment: What version of BeautifulSoup are you using?  I'm getting something very different when I parse that string.  Could you show the full code?

Comment: `>>> bs4.__version__
 '4.1.1'`.  Will add full code in edit